# Subquery or CTE to add additional column

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a large data sets of truck tickets which generate two lines of output per ticket. This is because the ticket has an "out" and "in" component to each ticket. I want to generate one line of output but include information from both the "out" portion of the ticket and the "in" portion.

```
SELECT Ticket_number, Oil_volume,Faciliy_ID,Ticket_Type
FROM Truckticket T
JOIN TBATTERY TB
ON TB.Battery_ID = T.Battery_ID
```

**My Output has two lines:**

| Ticket_number | Oil_volume | Facility_ID | Ticket_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | SK01 | O |
| 1 | 10 | SK02 | I |

Now, what I want my output to be when I use a where clause on `Facility_ID` `SK01`:

| Ticket_number | Oil_volume | Facility_ID | Facility_ID | Ticket_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | SK01 | SK02 | O |

I know I have to do this with a subquery or CTE to get `Facility_ID` `SK02` on the same line, but I'm stuck. I hope I have presented my question ok, my first time. Thanks!`

Comment: Provide sample data for `Truckticket` and `TBATTERY` or at least provide table reference in code like `T.Ticket_number`. Also, Do you need O as `ticket_type` always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a subquery or CTE, this looks like a good time to use aggregation and pivoting. With a small number of static types, a simple `MAX(CASE...` expression with a `GROUP BY` can pivot the rows to columns.

```
SELECT
    Ticket_number,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Ticket_Type = 'O' then Oil_volume else NULL END) Oil_volume_out,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Ticket_Type = 'I' then Oil_volume else NULL END) Oil_volume_in,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Ticket_Type = 'O' then Facility_ID else NULL END) Facility_ID_out,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Ticket_Type = 'I' then Facility_ID else NULL END) Facility_ID_in,
FROM Truckticket T
JOIN TBATTERY TB
ON TB.Battery_ID = T.Battery_ID
GROUP BY Ticket_number;
```